# MS Access connecting with Windows Username to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

```
Dim Cnxn As ADODB.Connection
Set Cnxn = New ADODB.Connection
With Cnxn
  .Provider = "MSDataShape"
  .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
  .Properties("Data Source").Value = dbserver
  .Properties("User ID").Value = Username
  .Properties("Password").Value = password
  .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = dbname
  .CommandTimeout = 120
  .ConnectionTimeout = 120
  .Open
End With
```

Above is how I connect from MS Access to SQL Server where username is a default SQL username. However, I would like to connect with the Windows username but don't have the time to create 100's of usernames on the SQL Server, one for each Windows user. Is there a nice way of doing this? This is for auditing purposes so I know who did what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Properties UserID` and `Password`, and replace with `Integrated Security` with a value of `true`.

```
.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = true
```

*Might be a capital `T` for `true`

Comment: and make sure the db server knows about the login or better still a group the user is am member of.